# Show if two lines intersect

Tags: linear-algebra

> Do the lines $ L_1=(0,2,3) +t\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $ L_2 = (0, 5, 1)+ s\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$intersect?

I believe one way to prove they intersect is to prove that once 2 coordinates are equal then the third must be equal. Like this

$x_1 = 0 + t = 0 + 0(s) = 0 $

$x_2 = 2 + 0(t) = 5+s = 0 $

$x_3 = 3 + 0(t) = 1 + 0(s) = 0 $

But I can't do it from this point because $t = 0$ and $s = -3$. Just by knowing this can I conclude they don't intersect or am I missing something.

Comment: Your approach works.  Since $3\not =0$, the $x_3$ coordinates never match, and the lines don't intersect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't conclude it from $t\ne s$, but in the third coordinate you ask that $3+ 0t=1+0s$ which cannot be satisfied and from that you can. You say these are $0$ but the first is $3$

Comment: but if we consider only the direction $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, arent they perpendicular? If so, they has to intersect somewhere right?

Comment: @Learner But its dot product is not 0 so they aren't orthogonal. Then they can not intercept. As in the example.

Comment: @Learner:  From the $x_1$ equation we conclude $t=0$, but don't know $s$.  Then from $x_2$ we conclude $s=3$.  Then if they are going to meet the $x_3$ coordinates have to match, which they don't.  Orthogonality has nothing to do with it.  Non-orthogonal lines can meet.